# Rewrite rule for the root file in nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I just want to redirect / to a different file rather than index.php/.html.

So on apache I can do this..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . /path/to/dir/index.html [L]
```

Trying this in nginx just doesn't even get run, it seems:

```
if (-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite /. /path/to/dir/index.html last;
}
```

Also tried this:

```
if ($request_filename ~ "/index.php"){
    set $rule_3 1$rule_3;
}

if ($args ~ "^$"){
    set $rule_3 2$rule_3;
}

if ($rule_3 = "21"){
    rewrite /. /wp-content/plugins/i-static/content/index.html last;
}
```

It acts like it doesn't even exist and just prints out index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to isolate the single URI `/`, use the `location =` variant. Try:

```
location = / { rewrite ^ /new/index.html last; }
```

This will perform an internal rewrite. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Yeah that's it. Silly and simple. Thanks!