# index.php not loading from ubuntu server VM (nginx & sftp)

Tags: php, nginx, virtualbox, xdebug, remote-debugging

I'll try to be short as it can get bloated.
I set up an ubuntu server 20.04 VM on an Oracle vbox.
I installed nginx, php7.4, Xdebug 3.

I configured everything properly for remote debugging and sftp ( I use PHPstorm), I forwarded the ports and customized my local hosts file.Everything works except...

when loading HTTP://127.0.0.2 it loads the default nginx landing page.My index.php file is uploaded in the root /var/www/my_domain folder through sftp. I created the server block for my_domain.

Still won't work. I am new to this so I am missing something.
If you need more info please request.
Any help appreciated!

Vhost config ( server block in nginx) - **php-projects** being my current domain and containing index.php:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/php-projects;
    server_name php-projects www.php-projects;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
}
```

Network settings from Vbox:
[image]

PS. I have tried :
[How to set index.html as root file in Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954255/how-to-set-index-html-as-root-file-in-nginx)

and

[Rewrite rule for the root file in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625086/rewrite-rule-for-the-root-file-in-nginx)

with no success.

Comment: Have you changed your root dir in your httpd.conf?

Comment: the conf.d folder seems to be empty on my machine... how can I find the default contents?What should it contain?

Comment: however, to add to that, nginx.conf contains the path to sites-enabled, where the server block ( apache virtual host) is set up to point to my root /var/www/my_domain.

Comment: My bad youre running Nginx, your conf should be at  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: [Check this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/deploying_different_types_of_servers/setting-up-and-configuring-nginx_deploying-different-types-of-servers)

Comment: No succes yet, I seem to have done it right , but somehow no...

Comment: change your index.php to index.html and see if it will serve that.

Comment: Apparently it won't. Changed the file extension and in the server block.

Comment: and nginx -t returns no syntax errors....

Comment: oddly enough, it does not load anything but downloads a file, seems an .msi?!, though no extension... ( my index.php is a simple test landing page, no file operations)

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954255/how-to-set-index-html-as-root-file-in-nginx)

Answer (score 1):

> "I configured everything properly for remote debugging and sftp"

Please post your xdebug configuration.

> "when loading HTTP://127.0.0.2"

From where ? Host machine or VM?

> "My index.php file is uploaded in the root /var/www/my_domain folder
> through sftp."

Please post your nginx vhost configuration

> "I created the server block for my_domain"

Where? Post the path to the file where you have done this

Comment: for Xdebug it's the default configuration, if you wish please point me to what exactly I can give you here

Comment: 127.0.0.2 from host as I forwarded the ports

Comment: I edited the question to add network settings and vhost config

Comment: if you need more info please ask as I am not very familiar yet with how this works